# List Files and Directory Segmented Does not retrieve last Modified date of files

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage-files

I have used **listFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented** for retrieving list of files within a directory. I can't find a way to get last modified date except calling another method **getFileproperties** for each file. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No. You would need to fetch the properties of each file. `listFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented` is essentially a wrapper over [`List Directories and Files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166980.aspx) REST API call which only returns the directory name and file name/size in the response. From the documentation link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/” ShareName="myshare" DirectoryPath="directory-path">
  <Marker>string-value</Marker>
  <MaxResults>int-value</MaxResults>
  <Entries>
    <File>
      <Name>file-name</Name>
      <Properties>
        <Content-Length>size-in-bytes</Content-Length>
      </Properties>
    </File>
    <Directory>
      <Name>directory-name</Name>
    </Directory>
  </Entries>
  <NextMarker />
</EnumerationResults>
```